# Can svg blobs contain hrefs?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, href, bloburls

I am building a website that displays content from a server (text, images, html, pdf, etc..). As the client does not know ahead of time what the content type is, it downloads the content, checks the content type, creates a blob url, and then renders it using the blob url in the src attribute. This saves having to download the content twice (once to check content type, another when the browser renders the content from src).

Some of the images are svg files that have hrefs to other files on the server. These hrefs do not work when the svg is src'ed by blob url. The hrefs work perfectly fine when src'ed by the normal url.

For example, if you had the following svg available at https://examplehost.com/sample.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</svg>
```

You could easily embed the svg on your webpage using the url in the src attribute

```
<img src="https://examplehost.com/sample.svg">
```

If, however, you convert the svg to a blob first

```
var response = await fetch("https://examplehost.com/sample.svg");
var blob = await response.blob();  
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

The href embedded in the svg will not work

```
<img src="blobUrl_goes_here">
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mil2d2/m2evta6w/91/)

Is it possible to have hrefs in blob svgs?

Comment: I think the issue is not the usage of the blob per se - but that an `img` element gets used to display that blob. Embedding SVG into an HTML document via `img` comes with certain restrictions, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_as_an_Image - and one of them is that the SVG can't load further external resources.

Comment: @CBroe That would make sense. Would your explanation still apply if resources are all on the same domain? (I should have made that clear in my question)

Comment: Yes, the origin doesn't matter, it is _just_ the fact that the resource is "external". But your code will be handling different types of content differently anyway, right? (Must be, `img` would not be suitable to display f.e. a PDF in the first place.) Then for an SVG don't create a blob URL and assign it as an image source - create a `div` instead, do `div.innerHTML = {the svg code}`, and then append that div to the document. Then it will not be affected by these restrictions.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe! Didn't even occur to me to just set the inner html. Appreciate the help.